# Displaying HTML Code not Plain text using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, html, winforms, stringbuilder

PROBLEM: How can I create a table using string builder formatted using html code? 
Sending email using appendformat works. But when displayed only in window form it will 
only display in plaintext.

Comment: Share your code. But first, read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't very clear, but I'll try:

If you want to display formatted HTML in a windows form, you'll have to use a WebBrowser control. If you want to edit the mail (or reply/forward), you'll need to use a RichText control and convert from HTML to RTF, put it in your richtext editor, and convert from RTF to HTML when you're done.

```
var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser.CreateControl(); 
webBrowser.DocumentText = <HTMLSTRING>;
while(_webBrowser.DocumentText != <HTMLSTRING>
{    
    Application.DoEvents();
} 
webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", false, null);
webBrowser.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", false, null);
<RichTextControl>.Paste();
```

Converting from RTF to HTML seems a bit more tricky, but not too much:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/10/20/rtf_5f00_html.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string a = WebUtility.HtmlEncode("<html><head><title>T</title></head></html>");
    string b = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a);

    Console.WriteLine("After HtmlEncode: " + a);
    Console.WriteLine("After HtmlDecode: " + b);
    }
}
```